# bash ничего не находит (MAC OS X)

Tags: bash, macos, cmd

В терминала при вызове команд, bash ничего не находит, хотя раньше все работало. После некоторых моих манипуляций, через командную строку не могу ничего вызвать.
К примеру,

```
iMac-Admin-2:~ oleg$ adb
-bash: adb: command not found
iMac-Admin-2:~ oleg$ npm
-bash: npm: command not found
iMac-Admin-2:~ oleg$
```

хотя и то, и другое раньше работало.

Как можно починить? Возможно все началось после *npm install express*, сложно сейчас найти последнюю команду, после которой так произошло.

Comment: Что значит "раньше"? Такого не бывает, чтоб все было хорошо, а потом БАЦ - "йа ничего не трогал, оно само!" - и перестало работать

Comment: @rjhdby
еще 30 минут назад все работало, но у меня не ставился appium и я пытался его установить. читал разные статьи и после какой-то команды, я не могу запустить ничего через командную строку. 
Скорее всего это случилось после запуска этих команд:
_ npm config get prefix
 sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
source ~/.profile_

Comment: Перелогиньтесь. Но если интересно покопаться, то `source ~/.profile` по идее должен восстановить переменные окружения, так же не помешает запустить `hash -r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ в английской версии **stackoverflow**.
Я в файле bash_profile не перевел каретку на новую строку.
Т.е. в конце всех переменных надо поставить было ENTER , перезагрузить Terminal и все заработало.